Runtime Error'3075' MS Access SET command error
I have a problem with runtime error 3075 in below command. I worked out, that the problem is probably related with this error, however I have no idea how to fix the rows and simple googling did not answer the question.
Sub t1()

    Dim sqlSt As String
        
        sqlSt = "UPDATE [tableA] SET [tableA].[status]=[tableB].[status] FROM [tableB] WHERE [tableA].[name=TableB].[name] AND [tableA].[training]=[tableB].[training];"
        
        Debug.Print sqlSt
        DoCmd.RunSQL sqlSt
    
    End Sub


See the example SQL there, Access does not have FROM in an UPDATE clause unless it's a subquery.
